# Homothetic preferences

Tags: microeconomics, utility, theory

I want to prove that if a utility function that represents $\succsim$ has constant marginal elasticity of substitution (MRS) in proportional expansions along rays, that is:
$$
MRS(x,y) = MRS(\alpha x, \alpha y), \ \forall \alpha > 0
$$
then $\succsim$ is homothetic.

The definition of homothetic preferences that I'm using is the one found in Mas-Colell et al.:

**Definition 3.B.6**: A monotone preference relation $\succsim$ on $X=\mathbb{R}^L_+$ is homothetic if all indifference sets are related by proportional expansion along rays; that is, if $x \sim y$ then $\alpha x \sim \alpha y$ for any $\alpha \ge 0$.

Comment: While this question is much better stated, the [older version](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/21465/homothetic-preferences-and-utility-functions) of this question now also has an answer to this one. Perhaps the two can be merged somehow.